# Rust constructor return owned vector with refs to local variable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm a newbie to rust...

I have a constructor implementation in which I first create a Vec of owned values. Then I place a reference of this Vector (&Vec) into a function which returns a data structure that holds references to values inside the passed vector.
I wan't to return the two data structures as owned values to construct my object.

```rust
struct NewTest<'a> {
    ints: Vec<i32>,
    int_refs: Vec<&'a i32>,
}

impl<'a> NewTest<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let ints: Vec<i32> = vec![10, 11, 12];
        let int_refs: Vec<&i32> = get_ref_vec(&ints);
        // cannot return value referencing local variable `ints`
        // returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
        Self { ints, int_refs }
    }
}

fn get_ref_vec(ints: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<&i32> {
    vec![&ints[0], &ints[1], &ints[2]]
}
```

Do I have to use Box somehow?

Comment: Please see [why it's discouraged to take `&Vec<i32>` as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)

Comment: Note that `&i32` is almost always useless. You can simply pass a `i32` instead, as it takes less space, access is more efficient, and you don't have to bother with lifetimes.